# Unable to locate certain <div> despite their presence

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape:
https://www.loft.com/loft-plus-floral-maxi-shirtdress/514793

I have been successful in scraping description. However, I am unable to scrape the product images and recommendations. The code that I am mentioning below have been used previously for some other fashion related sites but doesn't seem to be working for this.

```
#main method
d = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/fatima.arshad/Downloads/chromedriver')
d.get(url)
start = BeautifulSoup(d.page_source, 'html.parser')
Image_URL = self.saveImage("./products/", product_name, start)

recommendations = self.getRecommendations(start, d)

def getRecommendations(self,start,d):

    #code to scroll to the bottom of page
    recommended = []
    s = start.find_all('div', class_='swiper-container swiper-container-horizontal')
    while not s :
        s = start.find_all('div', class_='swiper-container swiper-container-horizontal')
    for data in start.find_all('div', class_='swiper-container swiper-container-horizontal'):
        for a in data.find_all('a'):
            print(a.get('href'))  # for getting link
            print(a.text)  # for getting text between the link
            recommended.append("https://loft.com"+str(a.get('href')))

def saveImage(self, foldername, product_name,start):
    ##some other code

    s = start.find('div', class_='swiper-wrapper')
    for i in start.find_all('div', class_='swiper-wrapper'):

        for img in i.select('img'):

            print(img['src'])

            urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://"+img['src'], foldername + "/" + product_name + str(c) + ".jpg")
            c = c + 1
```

The problem is that both of these methods return nothing. I put loop inside getRecommendations() in order for it get something in the end but still nothing.

Comment: Try to narrow down your posted code to include only the relevant parts. It'll be easier to help you.

Comment: @Itay please check now. I hope its more understandable

Answer (score 0):

The links are dynamically constructed. You can view in the network tab the GET request which retrieves in json format the info used to construct the new image urls.

You can mimic those steps:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests, re, json

p = re.compile(r'\((.*),')

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://www.loft.com/loft-plus-floral-maxi-shirtdress/514793')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    src = soup.select_one('.product-image img')['src'].split('?')[0]   
    r = s.get(f'{src}_IS?req=set,json&callback=s7R_1&handler=s7R_1&_=1')

data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
for item in data['set']['item']:
    i = item['i']['n']
    image_url = f'https://anninc.scene7.com/is/image/{i}?$pdp$'
    print(image_url)
```